# Webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use webservice in iphone objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497222/how-to-use-webservice-in-iphone-objective-c)

How to Call Webservice in iphone?

Comment: What type of webservice?

Comment: What did you try, etc... Type more than 6 words please.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) to create an Objective-C proxy for a SOAP webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:
[How to call soap service](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2841-resolved-how-call-soap-service.html)

Comment: yep..absolutely using json or xmlparsing

Answer (score 0):

Here..

Try this link.. [SoapCalls and XmlParsing example for Iphone](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

Also you can use WSDL2ObjC.. example for the following lies here..
[WSDL2ObjC](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/wsdl2objc.html)

Better go for the 1st one...its far more flexible than wsdl2objC..

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The web-service on ios are of 2 types XML-RPC and SOAP. You have to choose which web service you want to work with. Both as examples.

1.SOAP

```
tell application "URL of the soap web-service"
   call Soap{ option+l
   method name: method_name, SOAPAction: action_name, option+l 
   method namespace uri: namespace_name, parameters: parameters_list}
end tell
```

2.XMP-RPC

```
tell application "URL of xml web-service"
   call xmlrcp {method name: method_name, parameters: parameters_list}
end tell
```