# Webservice - iphone + php

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I want to create webservice in php and call in through iphone's View
   I have referred a lot for this.
   But can't get proper result.
   Please help me.
   Can You please let me know for xml parsing?

Comment: Please check these links :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860750/webservice-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial, for creating the webservice:

How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Then this tutorial for using that web service:

How to Write an iOS App That Uses a Web Service
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service