# Retrieve Data from iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, html

I would consider myself an average programmer and have taught myself the basics of Xcode4 using objective C for making iPhone applications.

My Question is,
How do I send data from my application to another source, Say a web page?
For example, The user enters text in a text box and at the click of a button the text is sent to and stored on a webpage?

Comment: Would you mean posting the data to a Database that holds this information. Then the data could be shown from the Database to the webpage. I think that would be the best approach.

Comment: Would it be difficult to store this data? Also the database would have to stored on a server of some kind? For the web page to retrieve it

Comment: there are plenty of ways. and all are documented and discussed on stackoverflow. You should search again.

Comment: and by the way: Xcode is just an IDE, the important tags and information would had been Objective-C and Cocoa(-Touch).

Comment: Ok I have had a look and found some interesting queries, I realize that I was just searching for the wrong statement, If you know of any simple tutorials please post a link as the one I am reading now is quite complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using web services.  Without going into a great amount of detail, I refer you to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497222/how-to-use-webservice-in-iphone-objective-c) that I believe is a good place to start.

Comment: Got it going now perfect

Answer (score 1):

I would use HTML GET or POST.  They are the simplest methods of putting information on a website.  There is some helpful documentation [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/html-get-vs-post/) on the difference between GET and POST.